# get javascript objects from LinkedHashMap<Sring,Integer[]> from server

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON at hands after an ajax request:

```
var data = {"key1":[1,2],"key2":[3,4]};
```

What is the syntax to access each key and value in javascript ?

I was thinking:

```
for(var i =0; i < data.size < i++){
     data[i][0]  data[i][1]   // ? maybe
}
```

I know for sure the integer array will only have two elements so that's not the concern.

Comment: The Java map will end up as a JavaScript object. The property names of that object will be the hash map `String` keys, and the values of the properties will be arrays of numbers.

Comment: If you actually trigger the ajax request in your browser, you can see exactly what the encoded object looks like in the browser's "Network" developer tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the structure you mentioned, the corresponding JSON would be something like this:

```
{
  "key1": [ ... ],
  "key2": [ ... ]
  ...
}
```

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to access the entries in JavaScript:

```
for(let [key, value] of data) {
  console.log(key, value);

  // Do other stuff here
}
```

Comment: Right and in the `for ... of` loop each `value` will be an array of numbers.